# Insufficient internal storage

Tags: insufficient-memory

I am using a *Samsung Galaxy* running Android 6.0 with an internal space of 16 GB. However, I have used 9.60 GB of it but when I want to transfer some stuff, it says the internal storage is full.

What has happened to the remaining 6.40 GB?

Comment: We have no idea. Go to **Settings** -> **Storage** and see.

Answer (score 0):

If the package says the device ships with 16GB, that includes the space needed for the operating system. With Samsung devices, that's usually about 6 GB or more.

For details and ways to deal with this, please take a look into our [insufficient-storage tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) and follow its links.